# Embedding Navigation Controller in a Tab Bar Controller changes Safe Area for View Controller

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9.2, ios11.2

I have a view for which I'd like to show it with a navigation at the top and a tab bar at the bottom. This view will be opened from a tab in top-level Tab Bar Controller.

When I embed a Navigation Controller in a Tab Bar Controller for this view, Safe Area inside my ViewController changes. Embed operation adds some offset from top and bottom.

Before embedding it looks like:
[image: before embed]

And after embedding it changes to this:
[image: after embed]

Views settings pane looks like the following:
[image]

Why is this happening? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Select your navigation controller and change the setting for top bar and bottom bar to inferred. Hope this helps, worked for me.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu top bar and bottom bar settings are all inferred already.

Comment: For navigation controller too? because when I created a new project and tried your scenario I faced same problem but changing the setting of navigation bar worked for me.

Comment: Yes, navigation controller's top/bottom bar settings were set to inferred already. I found the solution though. See my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by unticking `Shows Navigation Bar` setting for Navigation Controller.

[image: untick Shows Navigation Bar for Navigation Controller]